# 404 after deployment of a Symfony project

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have just deployed my application on the server.

On localhost I can use the URL http://localhost:80/autofill/has-data and I get an output. On the live server, I use the URL http://example.com/backend/autofill/has-data and I get a 404 error message.

My whole Symfony project is in the directory `backend`.

This is how my controller looks like:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/autofill/has-data", methods={"GET"})
 * @return Response
 */
public function hasData()
{
    $hasEnoughData = ($this->autofillService->hasEnoughData()) ? 1 : 0;

    return new Response($hasEnoughData);
}
```

Why do I get this 404 error?

Comment: do you have configurated mod rewrite or htaccess on your server or kind of this? https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/apache_router.html#generating-mod-rewrite-rules

Comment: @episch no, what I have is the .htaccess file in the directory `/public`, which is from Symfony itself. I didn't change anything.

Comment: Please add your vhost configuration. Most likely, it's the problem and not Symfony itself.